# posgresql/psql: '/home/path/to/my/file/file.txt' : Permission denied

Tags: ssh, copy, psql

I want to export table from ma database using remote access (ssh) and psql (\copy command) but failed

to resume:
I have a database named mydatabase and user named myuser granted on this database
table I try to extract is named mytable

1. I connect to my remote server using Putty
2. once connected, I run psql : `sudo -u postgres psql` (I tried to connect using myuser but failed because mysuser is unknown ???)
3. I connect to my database : `\c mybase`
4. I run \copy mytable TO '`/home/path/to/my/file/file.txt`'

and get error message:  '`/home/path/to/my/file/file.txt`' : Permission denied

as I said, I tried to connect using myuser thinking it could solve permission issue but don't know why it failed...

```
psql -d mydatabase -U myuser
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the operating system user you connect with using Putty is `x`.

Since you run `psql` as user `postgres` using the `sudo` command, it is the operating system user `postgres` that needs permissions to write `/home/path/to/my/file/file.txt`.

So user `x` must give `postgres` the required permissions.

Comment: how I should do that ?

Comment: Depends on your operating system. For Unix, look at the documentation of `chmod`.

Comment: OK chmod 757 to give access to "others" AND THEN I connect psql using sudo -u postgres psql command AND FINALLY run \copy crf_ran TO '/home/path/to/my/file/file.txt and it works

Comment: but now I did not manage to copy from remote to my local desktop using scp zebra@192.XXX.XX.X:/home/path/to/my/file/file.txt C:/path/to/my/folder but get an error

Permission denied, please try again.

Comment: You are trying to solve the problem the wrong way. Configure PostgreSQL so that the user (`x` in my answer) that you use to log into the machine is allowed to connect to the database. A simple change in `pg_hba.conf`.